# Como instalar android sdk?

Tags: android, flutter, vscode

necesito ayuda, estoy intentado adentrarme en el mundo del desarrollo de aplicaciones para telèfonos, hasta ahora he instalado Visual Studio Code y flutter,ademàs he descargado el sdk flutter. Todo me ha salido bien puse la ruta del sdk flutter en el entorno de variables, dentro de visual studio code instalè las extensiones de dart y flutter. El problema radica cuando intento correr el primer proyecto, no cuento con un dispositivo virtual, ademàs de que me salen dos errores màs como el no tengo el android sdk ni el avd manager. Tambien he bajado los sdk de android que he visto en internet pero al parecer le faltan elementos. En la imàgen muestro los elementos que tiene mi android sdk [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la siguiente es un video que vi donde muestra los elementos que deberìa tener la carpeta android sdk

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar con un link o indicarme bien se lo agradecerìa. Disculpen la extensiòn de mi texto. Gracias

Comment: es más fácil si usas android studio que ya trae todo integrado https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor?tab=androidstudio

Comment: también instale Android studio y sigo teniendo problema con el android sdk...he visto en algunos artículos que se puede instalar desde el mismo Android studio, pero lo he intentado y nada el SDK manager no me abre...me siento perdido

Comment: Con Android Studio abierto si haces clic en SDK Manager y no te abre? En caso que no , lo más facil es que borres Android Studio y lo reinstales de nuevo ya que seguramente algo te ha quedado mal instalado.

Comment: exacto con el android studio abierto el sdk manager no abre....he borrado e instalado ya 3 veces...y el mismo error...no c si tengo que agregar el jdk en las variables de entorno o algo mas...x cierto la versión que tengo descargada es la ultima disponible en la pagina oficial.

Comment: pero cuál es el error? Al menos muestra una captura..

Comment: no me da un error en si...es que simplemente cuando intento abrir el sdk manager este no abre...mi intención es instalar el andorid sdk desde el mismo android studio...y he leído que se hace a través del sdk manager...pero como dije anteriormente este no m abre.

Comment: asegurate de que java esté instalado. Escribe `java --version` en cualquier terminal y si te da error es porque no está instalado o porque las variables de entorno están mal configuradas

Comment: tengo instalada la version java 11.0.10 2021-01-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.10+8-LTS-162)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.10+8-LTS-162, mixed mode)